# Como pegar dados de uma lista apenas quando houver dois códigos iguais

Tags: java, lista

Atualmente consigo pegar apenas os dados diferentes de duas listas, por exemplo:

```
Lista X
Código 1
Código 2

Lista z:
Código 1
Código 3
```

Eu consigo pegar apenas o código `2` e `3`. Agora surgiu a necessidade de pegar os dados iguais, seguindo o exemplo de cima quero pegar apenas o código `1` pois ele existe nas duas listas.

Esse é o código que uso pra pegar os elementos diferentes de duas listas, e depois preencho uma tabela com esses dados:

```
List<Contratos> listaContratos = listarBanco();

        Cadastros cadastro = new Cadastros();
        ConsultaCadastro consultaCadastro = new ConsultaCadastro();
        List<Cadastros> listaCadastros;
        try {
            cadastro.setContratante(pesquisar.getText());
            cadastro.setCodigoContrato(pesquisar.getText());
            //Preenche uma lista de Cadastros
            listaCadastros = consultaCadastro.buscar(cadastro);

            Iterator<Cadastros> iter = listaCadastros.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Cadastros solicitacao = iter.next();
                for (Contratos s : listaContratos) {
                    Long t = s.getCodigoContrato();
                    if (t == Long.parseLong(solicitacao.getCodigoContrato())) {
                        iter.remove();
                        System.out.println("Remove");
                    }
                }
            }

            tblCadastros.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaCadastros));
```

Como consigo pegar apenas os iguais, ou então se for mais fácil como passo uma lista de parâmetros pra fazer uma consulta no banco, essas duas soluções resolveriam o meu problema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na coleção `Set` existe um método que faz exatamente isso, o nome dele é [`.retainAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)).

Exemplo pra usar:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(3);

Set<Integer> intersecao = new HashSet(list1);
intersecao.retainAll(list2);

System.out.println(intersecao);
```

> `[1]`

Um adendo, se você for trabalhar com uma classe que possui diversos atributos e você quer procurar apenas os de `código` igual, você pode sobrescrever seu método `.equals()`, exemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final SuaClasse other = (SuaClasse) obj;
    if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Caso você queira criar um `equals` para comparar com outra classe, precisa ser algo assim:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass() && obj.getClass() != OutraClasse.class) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() == obj.getClass()) {
        final SuaClasse other = (SuaClasse) obj;
        if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        final OutraClasse other = (OutraClasse) obj;
        if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Dessa forma ele pode ter 20 atributos diferentes, mas se o **código** for igual, ele retorna **verdadeiro** e funciona com o `.retainAll()`.

#### Colocando em prática

```
class SuaClasse {

    private int codigo;
    private String nome;

    // get/set

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass() && obj.getClass() != OutraClasse.class) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() == obj.getClass()) {
            final SuaClasse other = (SuaClasse) obj;
            if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            final OutraClasse other = (OutraClasse) obj;
            if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

E novamente na interseção:

```
List<SuaClasse> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(new SuaClasse(1, "maicon"));
list1.add(new SuaClasse(2, "maicon"));

List<SuaClasse> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add(new OutraClasse(1, "techies"));
list2.add(new OutraClasse(3, "techies"));

Set<SuaClasse> intersecao = new HashSet(list1); // pega o equals da SuaClasse
intersecao.retainAll(list2);

System.out.println("Tamanho: " + intersecao.size());
for (SuaClasse elemento : intersecao) {
    System.out.println(elemento.getCodigo() + " - " + elemento.getNome());
}
```

> Tamanho: 1
>
> 1 - maicon

### Importante!

#### Essa alteração no `.equals()` afeta todos os métodos que você compara os objetos, então se você usar algum `.indexOf()` ou até mesmo um `.contais()` o que prevalece é seu *equals* **sobrescrito**, ou seja, apenas comparando o **código**.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25122/discussion-between-maicon-carraro-and-techies).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.